# How to use LIKE operator with binary ordered-time UUID

Tags: mysql, binary

I have a MySQL 5.7 table with a binary(16) id column used as PRIMARY key.
The engine is InnoDb.

Rows are created with Doctrine using https://github.com/ramsey/uuid-doctrine#innodb-optimised-binary-uuids as per https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/12/19/store-uuid-optimized-way/

For instance the uuid `55a54172-f5e4-11e8-aa0d-fe02fd3f406` is stored as `HEX(id) = 11E8F5E455A54172AA0DFE02FD3F406` in the database

I'm trying to search for rows with the same string beginning.

Something like this with pseudo code

```
SELECT *
FROM log
WHERE id LIKE 11E8F5E4
```

I've tried to query

```
SELECT HEX(`id`) AS `id`
FROM `log`
WHERE (`id` & UNHEX('11E8F5E4')) = UNHEX('11E8F5E4')
LIMIT 10
```

which is fast but rows with a different prefix like `11E8E8AD47E47970B1C9525400B61105` are returned

**How may I do it while using the Btree index (for perf reason)?**

Comment: If you add data example and expected results that would be great. [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Off topic more or less: SQL is by definition **orderless**. Using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is **meaningless**.  Using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` will not guarantee the same results always even when running the same query twice because a SQL server is free to pick anny record from the table which matches as the "first" 10 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the straightforward approach with `LIKE`, and it seems to be working fine.

You need to make a binary string which has a % at the end:

```
SELECT ...
FROM table
WHERE field LIKE CONCAT(UNHEX('11E8F5E4'),'%')
```

Comment: thanks you, I was not aware that you can mix binary data with the percent char